# How to escape ListView name in SOQL RETURNING USING clause

Tags: salesforce, soql

List name: `mike's test view`

```
FIND {*@*.*} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Company USING ListView=mike's test view)

line 2:0 mismatched character '&lt;EOF&gt;' expecting '''
```

When escape with \:

```
FIND {*@*.*} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Company USING ListView=mike\'s\ test\ view)

Phone, Company USING ListView=mike\'s\ test\ view)
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:110
line 1:110 no viable alternative at character '\'
```

[Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_using_listview.htm#sforce_api_calls_sosl_using_listview) say nothing about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to use the api name and not the display name so it would be

```
FIND {*@*.*} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Company USING ListView=mike_s_test_view)
```

Comment: What do you mean? It's not a table or an object, it's one record of [ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_listview.htm?search_text=list%20view) with Name equal to `mike's test view`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have permissions to do do Edit the ListView and you would see the two fields up top one that has the display name the other has the API name which is basically the display name with special characters and spaces replaced with "_" character.  That is that name that you want to use the second one not the display name

Comment: Now I got it, there is another field `DeveloperName` which has to be used for that. Thank you!